# Is it correct to say 'estimate of probability density function'?

Tags: terminology, density-estimation

This question is about terminology:

I have a stochastic process from which I get a sample. Ideally I want to know the probability density function (pdf) associated with the process, but from  the data I only can get a sort of approximation of it. **Q1:** *Is it correct to say that it is an 'estimate' of the probability distribution?* I read about [estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator) and [estimands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimand) and it seems to me that the terms are not used for functions.

The process takes place in continuous time and last forever (arises from a physical system at equilibrium) and I only take many samples at intervals $\Delta t$. Suppose that:

1. The method used for obtaining the pdf would lead to exact discrete sample of the pdf (Dpdf) if all the infinite samples were taken.
2. From a finite sample I can get an 'estimate?' of the Dpdf and from this I can get the exact sample mean ($\int x p(x) dx$).
3. $\Delta t$ depends on the way in which the data is acquired, it can be reduced as desired, and it is independent of the mentioned method used to obtain the pdf (note, the pdf will be perfect if $\Delta t\to 0$ and $t\to \infty$).

**Q2:** Is it correct to say that the method for obtaining the sample of the pdf is *exact*? Or which term would be more appropriate from a statistical point of view.

Thanks in advance.